# Creation of buffer area of 20mtrs upon click event on the base layer

Tags: kml, buffer, openlayers-2, api

I have a base layer upon which i wish to import a kml with certain lat lons and create a buffer region of 20mtrs around any point upon click event.

i got google api for the same but want openlayers api to execute this on my base layer.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve one problem of displaying the kml using openlayers API. We can use Openlayers.Layer.GML

```
//Adding KML file to map
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("KML", "college.kml", 
           {
            format: OpenLayers.Format.KML, 
            formatOptions: {
              extractStyles: true, 
              extractAttributes: true,
              maxDepth: 2
            }
           }));
```